# Angular Ngx-smart-table, missing dependency on build (@angular/http)

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table, nebular

I have tried to use the ngx-smart-table following the instructions on the project page, but when i serve the project I get the following error:

ERROR in The target entry-point "ngx-smart-table" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/http
 - @angular/http/src/interfaces

If I try to use ng2-smart-table, I get a similar error:
ERROR in The target entry-point "ng2-smart-table" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/http

I have added the Ng2SmartTableModule to the dependecies in both the app.module.ts, and my module, and added the import in my component.

My packege json dependencies:
{
`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.7",
    "@nebular/auth": "^5.0.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.2",
    "ngx-smart-table": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
    "@schematics/angular": "~9.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }`
}

Anyone has any idea what I'm missing? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't think this ng2-smart-table package is compatible with angular cli 9. The only example I have found online is using cli7.

Comment: Ouch, I guess I will have to try and downgrade to angular 7 and try it out. The weird thing is that the Nebular version 5.0 is working (and requires angular 8+) and the ngx-smart-table still not working.

Comment: in that case delete node_module, and remove package-lock. do npm outdated and upgrade any package then npm install, and ng serve. sometimes updating screw up some library